# Interpreting Apache Access Log, Site with Forced HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, logging

On site example.com I have forced https with the following in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

A vendor is supposed to post data to https://www.example.com/membership/foobar.php and they insist they are using the https scheme for their posts.

Looking for their IP in the logs invariably follows this pattern:

```
[17/Mar/2016:00:15:11 -0400] "POST /membership/foobar.php HTTP/1.1" 302 1165 731 "-" "-"   
[17/Mar/2016:00:15:11 -0400] "GET /membership/foobar.php HTTP/1.1" 200 743 2623 "-" "-"    

[17/Mar/2016:17:37:58 -0400] "POST /membership/foobar.php HTTP/1.1" 302 1179 731 "-" "-"
[17/Mar/2016:17:37:58 -0400] "GET /membership/foobar.php HTTP/1.1" 200 743 2623 "-" "-"
```

As I read this it is a POST that receives a 302 which then is interpreted as a GET and I assume this is due to the htaccess rewriting a request for the http scheme, not https.

Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: I would think so, yes. They are requesting via POST http:// page, and get redirected, GET could be because of your .htaccess, or if have done like header() in your PHP code., in your .htaccess try [R=301,L], to signal that it is a permanent redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless until you have some other rule or code not shown here it appears `POST` request is landing on port 80 and getting redirected with 302 status. Keep in mind any 302/301 becomes a GET requests after redirection and **will cause loss of POST data in the process.**

Once should skip POST request for these redirects using a condition like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```